# Overflow-x:hidden conflict with CSS Flexbox in Chrome only

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm using css flexbox to do a header/body/footer layout. However if spicing up the outer-div with overflow-x:hidden, Chrome begins to crop the bottom (the status element) when reducing height of the viewport, and introduces a vertical scrollbar.

Firefox works as expected by shrinking the body-element height, and continue to show the statusbar when reducing the browser height.
Chrome restores the correct layout if reloading page, or changing the viewport width.

Stackblitz sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtapbp

The difference between Chrome and Firefox can be seen by showing the above stackblitz in the two browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The implied value of `min-height` (or `min-width` for default `flex-direction: row` orientation) is `auto` for flex layouts. For some reason, Chrome decides, that the size of the content that you have during initial page render should be treated as current `auto` value, and during window shrinking it does not recalculate the whole layout. Probably it is a bug in Chrome css layout engine. A solution for this is to add `min-height: 0` to the content+status div, as shown in [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtfz8k).

Comment: Oh Great Piotr, it works! This implicit min-height is a joker (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). Good explanation, I agree it must be a bug that Chrome decide for min-height to be set to the initial size, hereby preventing subsequent shrinking. I cannot see a good reason why min-height should take this over-size.
Worth noting though is that Chrome only make this decision when using overflow-x:hidden!? I fail to see the connection.

Comment: For me the problem appeared both with and without the overflow-x:hidden. However, toggling this css line in dev tools seemed to cause a layout re-calculation, which may seem as if one way or the other works fine, but even after that, if the window is resided, the issue persisted. Tested on chrome v 71, windows.